# How to refresh the view of a custom layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a custom TitleBar which subclasses RelativeLayout and creates its view by inflating an xml layout file. There's a TextView in it to display title, and the TitleBar class has a custom attribute called titleText. I have difined it in attrs.xml and called mTitleText.setText() in onFinishInflate(), and it works properly.

But then I want to change the title programmatically, so I add a public method setTitle(), in which the private String variable mTitle is modified and invalidate() and requestLayout() are called. However, it doesn't work and I realize that onFinishInflate() will be called only once. So how to update the TextView? Where should I call mTitleText.setText()? Should I override onDraw()?

Here is some of my code:

```
public class TitleBar extends RelativeLayout {
    private String mTitle;
    private TextView mTitleText;

    public TitleBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        retrieveProperties(context, attrs);
        initializeView(context);
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    private void retrieveProperties(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TitleBar, 0, 0);
        try {
            mTitle = a.getString(R.styleable.TitleBar_titleText);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    private void initializeView(Context context) {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.title_bar, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        mTitleText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        mTitleText.setText(mTitle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I find out the answer by reading `setTitle()` method of `android.widget.Toolbar`:

```
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
        if (mTitleTextView == null) {
            final Context context = getContext();
            mTitleTextView = new TextView(context);
            mTitleTextView.setSingleLine();
            mTitleTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
            if (mTitleTextAppearance != 0) {
                mTitleTextView.setTextAppearance(mTitleTextAppearance);
            }
            if (mTitleTextColor != 0) {
                mTitleTextView.setTextColor(mTitleTextColor);
            }
        }
        if (!isChildOrHidden(mTitleTextView)) {
            addSystemView(mTitleTextView, true);
        }
    } else if (mTitleTextView != null && isChildOrHidden(mTitleTextView)) {
        removeView(mTitleTextView);
        mHiddenViews.remove(mTitleTextView);
    }
    if (mTitleTextView != null) {
        mTitleTextView.setText(title);
    }
    mTitleText = title;
}
```

It turns out that I just need to call `mTitleText.setText()` in `TitleBar.setTitle()` and change `mTitle` simultaneously for further usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void updateTextView(String toThis) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(toThis);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to expressly write 'return' at the end of a 'void' method. But, more important: please answer the whole question. What about "Where should I call mTitleText.setText()? Should I override onDraw()?"